# Gradle : Assembling jar and getting "annot change dependencies of configuration ':compile' after it has been included in dependency resolution"

Tags: gradle, jar

I have simple gradle project

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/libs/lib"
    from configurations.runtime
}

jar {
    dependsOn copyToLib
    manifest {
        attributes (
            "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
        )
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'org.antlr:antlr4:4.0'
}
```

I am getting an error telling me that

```
Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':compile' after it has been included in dependency resolution
```

whenever I try `gradle jar` command.

What's wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have meet same problem,after some research i find that you need put code in dofirst

```
jar {
    doFirst
    {
    dependsOn copyToLib
    manifest {
        attributes (
            "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
        )
    }
    }
}
```